# How to locate mouse input on graphics

Tags: java, graphics, mouse

I was wondering if someone could tell me how to find the coordinates of the mouse in a window, and whether that mouse has been clicked or not.

Answer (score 1):

For mouse move/location, use a MouseMotionListener on your Component.
For mouse click, use a MouseListener on your Component.

```
component.addMouseListener(...);
component.addMouseMotionListener(...);
```

You can use the same listener for both, and there is an adapter class that you can extend (`MouseAdapter`) to only override event-methods that you care about.

Read all about mouse listeners [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html).

Answer (score 0):

You could either go and read Java documentation on Mouse events and listeners or see [this example](http://beginwithjava.blogspot.com/2008/08/simple-mouse-interaction-in-java.html), it covers exactly what you are looking for: mouse clicks and mouse positions on a `JComponent`